# Application building error for Opendaylight Sodium

Tags: java, opendaylight

I want to deploy an application for OpendayLight Controller. 
So, I am following this guide: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-sodium/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html

My steps are quite simple:

1. Setting up the infrastructure (correct settings.xml, install maven,
   install jdk);
2. Downloaded example module : 
   **mvn archetype:generate
   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.1** 
   Giving these info:

> ```
> Define value for property 'groupId': : org.opendaylight.example 
> Define value for property 'artifactId': :  example 
> Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
> Define value for property 'package':  org.opendaylight.example: : 
> Define value for property 'classPrefix':
> ${artifactId.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}${artifactId.substring(1)}
> Define value for property 'copyright': : Copyright (c) 2015Yoyodyne, Inc
> ```

3. Run **mvn clean install** and after several minutes, it returns an
   error ([here the error log](https://lists.opendaylight.org/g/controller-dev/attachment/14928/0/compile_error.txt)).
   So I cant compile the project.

---

Can anybody help me to troubleshoot it ?
Thanks a lot

**UPDATE:** New logs are available at https://lists.opendaylight.org/g/controller-dev/message/14938

Comment: ```[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default) on project odl-hello-api: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/vnf/onap_plugin/hello/features/odl-hello-api/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.```

Looks like you have tests failing and that's what is preventing your build

Comment: Added new logs at https://lists.opendaylight.org/g/controller-dev/message/14938

Answer (score 0):

this line stands out to me:

```
java.rmi.NotBoundException: b171a475-c036-43f1-a98d-c8cd8835aec9
```

Is there some networking port your application is trying to open that is
already being used (bound to) another process running on the same system?

Comment: It could be a port conflict, or it could be that the SFT container failed to come up (surprise, surprise).

Comment: I think that new logs show that the binding error is due to manifest not exists.